# Where to store a common PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase subclass

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a growing BaseTestCase that extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. I have 2 repositories which use a common library (all internal company code).

Both repositories require most of the BaseTestCase functionality. So my question is;

Do i store the BaseTestCase class in the common library and create a dependancy on phpunit. Or do i duplicate the BaseTestCase into each repository? Or is there a solution i cant see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manager your dependencies. I'd recommend creating a **separate composer package** in its own repository solely for your `BaseTestCase` class. You can then require it from each of your repositories.

```json
"require-dev": {
    "your-company/test-case": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "<your clone url>"
    }
]
```

This way you don't duplicate code across repositories, and you avoid polluting your common library with testing tools.

Check out the composer documentation on [private repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories) for more information.

Comment: Since it's been a while i'll accept this as the answer. It also makes a lot of sense.